# how to bind "next tag" / "prev tag" in emacs

Tags: emacs, etag

Sort of an emacs noob, I am looking for how to bind the equivilent of C-u M-. to M-right, and C-u M-* to M-left, but I have now idea what is being called with the C-u modifier. When I describe-key on it, it says "universal-argument", and talks about adding numeric modifiers to other functions, which is totally not whats happening in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of `find-tag`, it seems that `C-u M-.` corresponds to `(find-tag TAGNAME t)`. I cannot find any difference between `M-*` and `C-u M-*`, but maybe you have a different version of Emacs?

Comment: that totally makes sense.. I hit C-h k and started typing the command, which gave me the docs on c-u. should have just looked at m-. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a note that if you're using "anything" completion, `anything-c-etags-select` works great.  Also `anything-imenu` for navigation within file.

Comment: You need only [`icicle-find-tag`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Emacs_Tags_Enhancements), which is a [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands#multi-command).  It does everything that you would normally need to use `find-tag` (`M-.`), `tags-loop-continue` (`M-,`), `tags-apropos`, and `list-tags` for.  In _Icicle_ minor mode, (`M-.`) is by default bound to `icicle-find-tag`.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this in your init-file (.emacs)

```
(defun testfnc ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg 4))
    (call-interactively 'find-tag)
    )
  )

(global-unset-key (kbd "M-,"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-,") 'testfnc)
```